# Cant run my nodejs and typescript project, and I am getting ".ts as an unknown file extension"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm now getting this error:

> `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

This occurred after adding `"type": "module"` into the `package.json`

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typeorm": "^0.2.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And I am running version nodejs - v14.16.0 and typescript - v4.1.4

Comment: [As far as I know that is not a valid option for package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json). Why did you include it?

Comment: I found that in order to use the import syntax (ESModules), I had to add "type": "module", since I was getting a "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error

Comment: That has nothing to do with package.json and in any case shouldn't matter at all for a Typescript app. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` are mutually exclusive.
Don't know if this is the real problem, though. Also I would remove the include and exclude blocks, in this case I think they're doing nothing.

And double-check that you require the module in the dist folder.